# Internet Explorer not writing cookies when setting 'remember me'

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cookies

In our software we have a asp:login control which looks like the following:

```
                    <asp:Login ID="LoginControl"
                    ToolTip="" runat="server" MembershipProvider=<MembershipProvider>
                    UserNameLabelText="Username:" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E8E9"
                    BorderWidth="0px" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Arial,Sans-Serif"
                    Width="220px" LoginButtonText="Login" 
                    TitleText="" onloggedin="LoginControl_LoggedIn" PasswordRecoveryText="Forgot your password?"
                    PasswordRecoveryUrl="/PasswordRecovery.aspx" 
                    meta:resourcekey="LoginControlResource1">
                    <LabelStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <TextBoxStyle BorderColor="#E7E8E9" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
                        CssClass="TextBoxStyle" Width="140px" />
                </asp:Login>
```

It does not seem to say to show 'remember me', but it does by default.

The problem is as follows:

1. Logging in to a domain outside of our network:
   When using internet explorer and remember me is clicked, the web application does not redirect and instead reloads the login page. I attached fiddler to it and found it was not writing anything to any cookies.
2. Logging in to a domain on our network:
   When using internet explorer and remember me is clicked, the web app directs user to a welcome page as expected. Fiddler also showed writing to a cookie.

I set the privacy on IE to allow all cookies still with no luck. This behavior does not exist on chrome or firefox, they both work properly. This problem also exists for all version of IE, 8,9,10 to be exact.

Our application does not manipulate or override any cookie or authentication behavior that .net already provides in its frame work.

Does anyone have any idea why IE will not write to a cookie for a domain outside our network but writes it properly to one in our network?

Answer (score 0):

Check Tools-> Internet options -> Security -> Custom level for both Internet and Local Intranet zones.

It contains a setting for User Authentication where by default, automatic logon with is set for Local Intranet. Try to configure the same for Internet.

It might be useful to know that you can configure IE security zones via GPO

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2012/06/05/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-security-zone-sites-using-group-polices.aspx